# I don't care for him so much. But SHE, I care a great deal for

Tags: objective-case

> I don't care for him so much. But **she**, I care a great deal for.

1. In this scenario, isn't it correct to say "She" rather than than "Her?" 
   (ex: Her, I care about vs. She, I care about.)
   My wife thinks it's "Her" instead of "She." Just trying to settle an argument.
2. Is this sort of an improper way to shape the sentence? I feel like it's technically OK, but it's more acceptable to say "I don't care much for him, but I care a great deal for her.)

Comment: It works, note that there's no parallelism, though . "I don't care for him so much. But she (**is one**), I care a great deal for." We **do not** use *her* in this form. Alt: "I don't care for him so much. But I care a great deal for **her**." (The sentence structure is different; so the case.) HTH.

Comment: Well, we certainly do use *her* in that inversion. Your supposed "(is one)" deletion is rather a stretch, IMO. It's more likely that the *for* in the first sentence would still linger in the air and attempt to govern the pronoun in the second, at least until that final *for*.

Comment: I agree that inferring "(is one)" is a stretch, and if you do insert it, then the comma does not belong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a sentence that begins with “them”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510964/is-there-a-sentence-that-begins-with-them) (a good answer on the OSV structure).

Comment: It's OK to use _She_ in paralle, if you don't move it, but rather copy it: i.e, _But she, I care a great deal for her._ Without the _her_, however, it's movement, and it would have to be _her_.

Answer (score 2):

No, in this scenario it is *not* correct to say "she". "She" is the object, not the subject.

You wouldn't say "I care a great deal for she." Changing the sentence order doesn't change that. It does change the rhythm and flow of the sentence; whether that's "proper" or not depends on your goal.

Answer (score 0):

No, it should be 'her'. Because what you are saying is, I don't care for him but I do care for her.